# Angular 2 How to create components dynamically from json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have some data from json, and i should create and paste these components to page dynamically. I have 4 element types (Text, video, Link, Image).

```
1: [
        {
            type: 'Text',
            id: 1,
            active: true
            data: {x: 10,y: 20,width: 150,height: 50,text:"Text",fontSize: 14}'
        },
        {
            type: 'Video',
            id: 2,
            active: true
            data: {x: 30,y: 40,width: 200,height: 100,src:"http://bbbbbb"}
        }
    ],
    2: [
        {
            type: 'Link',
            id: 3,
            active: true
            data: {x: 10,y: 20,width: 150,height: 50,url:"http://bbbbbb"}
        }
    ],
    3: [
        {
            type: 'Image',
            id: 3,
            active: false
            data: {
                x: 10,
                y: 20,
                width: 300,
                height: 100,
                src: 'http://bbbbbb'

            }
        }
    ]
```

I've created one parent Class for these elements with general properties.

```js
export abstract class Element implements IElement{

  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  active: boolean;
  id: number;

}

export interface IElement {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  active: boolean;
  id: number;
}
```

But i do not understand how i can extend the abstract parent class and paste these elements to component dynamically, like:

```html
 <text></text>
 <video></video>
 <image></image>
```